# Shortest path for undirected weighted graph without source and target vertices

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-theory

My teacher gave us a list of countries and asked us to find the shortest path(visits all the nodes exactly once) in the shortest time possible. I've created a matrix whose vertices are countries and edges are flights between them (weights are the amount of time for each flight). But I have no idea how to do this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). You can search it for yourself, there are several solutions on the web for it.

Comment: Here is a tutorial how to solve it in python: https://towardsdatascience.com/solving-travelling-salesperson-problems-with-python-5de7e883d847

Comment: I used TSP, but it just outputs the right result when the input matrix is a complete graph